# Given an operator and its' representation in a non-orthogonal basis. Is it normal?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given T, an operator in $V = \mathbb {C^2}$ and a basis $B = \{ (1,1), (1,0) \}$. Is $T$ a normal operator if $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 2 & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$ and $[T^{*}]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -i & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$.

Now this basis is not an orthogonal basis, so can I still check if $[T]_B [T^{*}]_B = [T^{*}]_B [T]_B$? if not, then what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr B = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$, the standard basis in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $M$ be the matrix that represents the change of basis from $\mathscr B$ to $B$. We have:
$$
[T]_{\mathscr B} = M^{-1} [T]_B M, \quad [T^*]_{\mathscr B} = M^{-1} [T^*]_B M
$$

Thus:
$$
[T]_{\mathscr B} [T^*]_{\mathscr B} =  M^{-1} [T]_B M M^{-1} [T^*]_B M = M^{-1} [T]_B [T^*]_B M
$$

Similarly:
$$
[T^*]_{\mathscr B} [T]_{\mathscr B} =  M^{-1} [T^*]_B [T]_B M
$$

It follows that $[T]_B [T^*]_B = [T^*]_B [T]_B$ if and only if $[T]_{\mathscr B} [T^*]_{\mathscr B} = [T^*]_{\mathscr B} [T]_{\mathscr B}$.

Comment: He's essentially saying normalcy is invariant under similarity transforms...

Comment: @TheNotMe Happy to help!

Comment: Its a good time to wish me luck on my exam on thursday, Algebra 2!

Comment: @TheNotMe I wish you good luck. Keep studying and I'm sure you'll do well.

Comment: I got to a point where I just can't go on, my brain is gonna explode of Gram Schmidt, inner product, diagonalization and all! Thank you!

Comment: Hey one more question. What if I get $[T]_B [T^*]_B \neq [T^*]_B [T]_B$, does it certainly say that it is not normal? I mean is it an iff what we got?

Comment: @TheNotMe It is indeed an equivalence (iff) relation. If $[T]_B[T^*]_B \ne [T^*]_B[T]_B$ then $M^{-1}[T]_B[T^*]_BM \ne M^{-1}[T^*]_B[T]_BM$. Hence $[T]_{\mathscr B}[T^*]_{\mathscr B} \ne [T^*]_{\mathscr B}[T]_{\mathscr B}$. I'll update my answer.